# 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException'"Tried the other solution but never gotten to the point of resolving"

Tags: vb.net

i've tried the other solution(like changing item that should be shown on data) but i think i've never gotten the point to resolving. Thank you in advance whoever can answer my problem...

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

---

```
Private Sub dgEmp_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles dgEmp.Click
    LoadEmployeeInfo(dgEmp.SelectedRows.Item(0).Index)

End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub LoadEmployee(Optional q As String = "")
    list.Query = "Select id,lastname,firstname,middlename,sss,philh,pag,rate,cola,mStatus,free_insurance,mp,mpvalue from tblemployee where (lastname like'%" & q & "%'  or firstname like'%" & q & "%' or middlename  like'%" & q & "%') and deactive='No' order by lastname,firstname,middlename"

    list.datagrid = dgEmp
    list.LoadRecords()
    If list.RecordCount = Nothing Then Exit Sub

    LoadEmployeeInfo(dgEmp.SelectedRows.Item(0).Index)
End Sub
Public Sub LoadEmployeeInfo(index As Integer)
    With dgEmp.Rows(index)
        id = .Cells(0).Value
        lblName.Text = .Cells(1).Value & ", " & .Cells(2).Value & " " & .Cells(3).Value
        rpd = .Cells(7).Value
        lblRate.Text = Format(rpd, "#,##0.000000000")
        cola = .Cells(8).Value
        lblAllo.Text = Format(cola, "#,##0.000000000")
        otrate = (rpd / 8) * 1.25
        lblOTRate.Text = Format(otrate, "#,##0.000000000")
        IsSSS = ConvertToBoolean(.Cells(4).Value)
        IsPH = ConvertToBoolean(.Cells(5).Value) 'add
        IsPAG = ConvertToBoolean(.Cells(6).Value) 'pos
        IsMP = ConvertToBoolean(.Cells(11).Value)
        IsFI = ConvertToBoolean(.Cells(10).Value)
        CStatus = .Cells(9).Value
        MPV = .Cells(12).Value
    End With

    ThisPayroll.Query = "Select * from tblpayroll where payrollperiod=? and empid=?"
    ThisPayroll.AddParam("@payrollperiod", GetPeriod)
    ThisPayroll.AddParam("@empid", id)
    ThisPayroll.ExecQuery()

    If ThisPayroll.RecordCount = Nothing Then
        isUpdate = False
        txtReg_Days.Text = 0
        txtReg_OT.Text = 0
        txtSP_Days.Text = 0
        txtSP_OT.Text = 0
        txtHoliday.Text = 0
        txtHolidayOT.Text = 0
        txtLate.Text = 0
        txtAdjustment.Text = 0
        txtSSSL.Text = 0
        txtHDMFL.Text = 0
        txtCA.Text = 0
        txtDMA.Text = 0
        txtRice.Text = 0
        txtCloth.Text = 0
        txtEmpMed.Text = 0
        txtLaundry.Text = 0
        txtMeal.Text = 0
    Else
        With ThisPayroll.DataSource
            isUpdate = True
            txtReg_Days.Text = .Rows(0)("regday")
            txtReg_OT.Text = .Rows(0)("ot")
            txtSP_Days.Text = .Rows(0)("spday")
            txtSP_OT.Text = .Rows(0)("spdayot")
            txtHoliday.Text = .Rows(0)("lholiday")
            txtHolidayOT.Text = .Rows(0)("lhot")
            txtLate.Text = .Rows(0)("hlate")
            txtAdjustment.Text = .Rows(0)("salary_adj")
            txtSSSL.Text = .Rows(0)("sss_loan")
            txtHDMFL.Text = .Rows(0)("pag_loan")
            txtCA.Text = .Rows(0)("cash_advance")
            txtDMA.Text = .Rows(0)("depmed")
            txtRice.Text = .Rows(0)("ricesub")
            txtCloth.Text = .Rows(0)("clothing")
            txtEmpMed.Text = .Rows(0)("empmed")
            txtLaundry.Text = .Rows(0)("laundry")
            txtMeal.Text = .Rows(0)("meal")

        End With
    End If
    Compute()
End Sub
```

Comment: That would happen if `dgEmp.SelectedRows` is empty, which the code doesn't check for.

Comment: can i know what code is that?

Comment: The line where the exception occurs in the code you posted.

Comment: Why'd you tag this `[C#]`? It's VB code

Comment: sorry bout that..

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot make sure that something is selected elsewhere, you can last-minute check it like this:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.SelectionChanged
    If dgEmp.SelectedRows.Count > 0 Then
        LoadEmployeeInfo(dgEmp.SelectedRows.Item(0).Index)
    End If
End Sub
```

It works only because you're using index zero, or else you would have to be careful for your index, too. Of course, this is assuming that `dgEmp` is not Nothing...

Also, notice that I attached this to the `SelectionChanged` event, as I don't think that the `Click` event will give you what you want, but I'll let that part for you to deal with. Have fun!